# How to handle file permissions with git commit when submitting on computers with different default file permissions

Tags: git

When committing and submitting from different computers with different file permissions a problem arises: with every `git commit` all files get flagged as changed, e.g.,

```
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

This floods the diff function. How do you handle this?

Comment: `git config core.filemode false` if you've got a repo mounted on unix that you have to e.g. samba-share to windows boxes and commit directly to from them rather than pushing.

Comment: @jthill Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jthill said in the comments, `git config core.filemode false` will disable filemode for the current repository.

`git config --global core.filemode false` will disable it globally (in all repos).

`git -c core.fileMode=false diff` will disable it for the diff command only.